# How to imagine the difference between the following schemes?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes

Consider $A=\operatorname{Spec} k[x]_{(x)}[t]$ and $B=\operatorname{Spec} k[x,t]_{(x)}$ for a field $k$ (Vakil, note 11.3.8). For me, both are infinitesimal neighborhoods of an affine line - the former is the product of an infl nbhd of a point on a line with a line, the latter is simply an infl nbhd of a line on an affine plane. How should I imagine the difference between them, or are they too sophisticated?

Comment: @oxeimon: Maybe, the word germ is better? (there are completions, non-radical ideals and localizations, and not so many geometric words)

Comment: probably, though I guess it doesn't exactly cause any confusion here so I deleted my comment

Comment: @user26857 $B$ has $1/t$, $A$ doesn't.

Comment: well here's a thought: $A$ is dimension 2 but $B$ is dimension 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very interesting and pedagogical question!

1) The underlying set of the scheme  $A=\operatorname{Spec} k[x]_{(x)}[t]$ is the union of
a) The generic point $\eta =(0)$ of the plane $\mathbb A^2_k$
b) The  $y$-axis $V(x)\subset \mathbb A^2_k$  .
c) The generic points $\mathfrak p$ of all the irreducible curves $V(\mathfrak p)\subset \mathbb A^2_k$  corresponding to prime ideals $\mathfrak p\subset k[x,y]$ of height $1$.
[Unimportant observation: $(x)$ appears both in b) and c)]
Note carefully that the scheme $B$  is **not** a subscheme of $\mathbb A^2_k$ because it is not locally closed.
As  user oxeimon excellently commented, $A$ has dimension $2$.

2)  The scheme $B=\operatorname{Spec} k[x,t]_{(x)}$  is the spectrum of a discrete valuation ring.
It is thus of dimension $1$ and has only two points, namely the generic point $(x)$ of the $y$-axis and the generic point $(0)$ of $\mathbb A^2_k$.
Here also $B$ is  not a subscheme of $\mathbb A^2_k$, although its underlying set consists of two points of the plane.

3) It should now be clear that *neither* of the schemes $A,B$ is an infinitesimal neighbourhood of the $y$-axis $V(x)\subset \mathbb A^2_k$.
The first infinitesimal neighbourhood of $V(x)$ is actually $V(x^2)=\operatorname{Spec} k[x,y]/(x^2)$ .

Comment: Could you please replace "The scheme ... is, set-theoretically, the union ..." by "The underlying set of the scheme ... is the union ..."? :-) Otherwise, great answer!

Comment: Thanks, @Martin: I have modified my answer acording to your suggestion. And welcome back to this site !